# java script submitting form after validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a little problem. I have a form, and my js validate it.Then, I need to submit the form if validation is success , and prevent submitting if the validation is not success. I tried to  use addEventListener (submit,function). But I don`t know how to do this. What is the best way to make this without using JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your function using onsubmit event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
   var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
   if (x==null || x=="")
  {
     alert("First name must be filled out");
     return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()"   method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: then call that function onsubmit="return myFunctionValidatingInput()". Here i have given you rough sketch how ur code will be

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a form with a name, you can call submit from javascipt or not call it if validation is not passed:

```
  //HTML
  <form name="myform">
  ......
  </form>

  //JS after validation checks, you set validation_errors = true or false
  if validation_errors:
     document.forms["myform"].submit();
```